# Topology of two circles

Tags: general-topology

I'm thinking of two disjoint circles in ~$\mathbb{R}^2$ for an example of basic topology; the axioms are telling me that they are both open, but they seem to contain all of their end points (so thus they're closed) .... maybe they are open because in $\mathbb{R}^2$ there is an open ball around them. Pls give me a point of view towards embeddings of shapes in a space.

Answer (score 1):

Sets are not doors. A set may well be both closed and open. And, in any topological space $X$, there are two such sets: $X$ and $\emptyset$.

Comment: A subset $A$ of a circle $C$ is open if there is an open subset $A^\ast$ of $\mathbb R^2$ such that $A=C\cap A^\ast$. In particular, $C$ itself is open, since $C=C\cap\mathbb R^2$. And $\emptyset$ is open, since $\emptyset=\emptyset\cap C$.

Comment: No. Why. A singleton is a closed subset of the circle, but it is not open.

Comment: @fia presheaf intervals are not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: What is an interval in the context of subsets of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Chapter 2 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (aka Baby Rudin) is more than enough.

Comment: As I wrote, if you take $A^\ast=\mathbb R^2$, then $A^\ast$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ and $C=C\cap A^\ast$.

Comment: Points being internal or not is something that is relevant in the context of intervals of $\mathbb R$, not in this context.

Comment: I say that $C$ is an open subset of $C$ (not of $\mathbb R^2$), because there is an open subset $A$ of $\mathbb R^2$ (namely, $A=\mathbb R^2$) such that $C=C\cap A$. In particular, I am talking about the subspace topology of $C$.